# SQL query for selecting all pk/fk in a database

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

I tried searching for a query that gives out all pk and fk of a big database. As I couldn't find any good query I came up with a solution.

```
SELECT 
    cols.table_name, cols.column_name, cols.position, cons.status, cons.owner
FROM 
    all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
WHERE 
    cols.owner = 'DATABASE_NAME'
    AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'
    AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
    AND cons.owner = cols.owner
ORDER BY 
    cols.table_name, cols.position;
```

The only thing that has to be changed is 'DATABASE_NAME' into the specific database name!

My question would be if there is an "easier" way to get all primary keys from one big database?

Comment: You mean *schema* name, not *database* name *8-) Also the distinction may not matter for your situation but this will only get keys on objects you can see; the `dba_*` views would show everything, but you might not have access to those anyway. Aside from using old-style joins this seems pretty easy, so not really sure what you're expecting...

Comment: The details on the all_constraints can be found, as per this you have covered already in your query.  Also have the cons.constraint_type ='R' as well along with 'P' to include foreign keys https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1037.htm#i1576022

Answer (score 0):

Another version of the query can be used to get the foreign-key relationship with the table as follow:

```
SELECT constr.table_name,
    column_name,
    position,
    constr.constraint_name,
    DECODE (constraint_type, 'P', 'Primary Key', 'Foreign Key') key_type,
       (SELECT constr2.table_name
        FROM all_constraints constr2
        WHERE constr2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = constr.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME) fK_to_table
    FROM all_cons_columns conscol, all_constraints constr
   WHERE     conscol.constraint_name = constr.constraint_name
         AND conscol.table_name = constr.table_name
         AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P', 'R')
         --AND constr.table_name = 'MYTEBLE' (your table here)
ORDER BY table_name, constraint_type, position;
```

output would be in something below format

```
TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME     POSITION   CONSTRAINT_NAME  KEY_TYPE     FK_TO_TABLE
ACCOUNT     ACCOUNT_ID          1        ACCOUNT_PK     Primary Key     
ACCOUNT     ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID     1        ACCOUNT_FK3    Foreign Key  ACCOUNT_TYPE
```